# Droos Rule Engine - Calling a utility function integrated with database from .drl file

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine

I have a scenario if the fact contains a particular value, then I wanted to call a utility function which will invoke the database and populate some values for fields. Is it okay to call data base function from the utility class which is invoked from drl file?

Comment: you will need to notify Drools engine of the facts being updated in some of their fields, by using Drools API pertaining to fact handles.

Comment: You'll need to make sure that utility function handles all transaction management, retries, connection pooling, etc. But otherwise, what do you mean by "is it okay"?

Comment: hi Roddy, Thanks for the reply, all database related things like txn management, retries all will be handled in using spring so no problem in that area. What I meant "is it kay" is, the approach is fine to call the database or I/O calls inside drools context, or is there any other way to handle it.

Comment: "is approach fine" ... are you asking for opinion? I'm looking for an objective question  in what you're asking but it sounds like you ware looking for an opinion instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a general answer, you can call a db fonction **in the action part (then part)** of your rule to update your Working Memory objects

However, you'll have to notify Drools this object has been modified using **update keyword** see  [DRL Then reference](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-THEN-con_drl-rules)

I would strongly advice **against** calling a db method in the **condition (if part)** of the rule, as such methods can be called many times unknowingly.

Best

Emmanuel

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I want to call only in the action part not in the condition part.

Comment: One more thing, is it possible to change the drl file during run time and reload it without restarting the server? Mine is a spring boot application.

Comment: Hi,
you can do a hot ruleset deploy 

- on a standalone application with your own ruleset loading code using a [kie scanner](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#kie-scanner-proc_packaging-deploying) 

- using the [REST API](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#kie-server-rest-api-con_kie-apis) to update a ruleset container, if you use the [Kie Execution Server](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_ch.kie.server)

Hope this helps,

Best